# Function maxRecursionDepth reached, even after adding a visited dictionary

Tags: python, graph

This is the question:

[image: This is the question]

My code is:

```
count = 0
visited = {}

def BackAndForth(AList,end1,end2):
  global count
  global visited

  for i in AList.keys():
    visited[i] = False
  print(AList[end1])
  visited[end1] = True
  if(end2 in AList[end1]):
    count+=1
  for i in AList[end1]:
    if(i!=end2 and not visited[i]):
      visited[i] = True
      BackAndForth(AList,i,end2)

  return count

Alist = {
    0 :[2,3,6],
    1 :[3,5,6] ,
    2 :[0,3,4],
    3 :[0,1,2,4],
    4 :[2,3,5],
    5 :[1,4,6],
    6 :[0,1,5],
}
end1=0
end2=1
print(BackAndForth(Alist,end1,end2))
```

This function is recurring infinitely even though I added a visited dictionary.

Comment: Sounds like there must be something wrong with the portion of the code that uses the visited directories to avoid unnecessary recursive calls. I suggest creating the simplest test case possible and debug using that.

Answer (score 2):

You set the `visited` dictionary to `False` at the beginning of the recursive method:

```
for i in AList.keys():
    visited[i] = False
```

This will reset the visited list on each call and thus start all over again.

Instead, use `None` as the default parameter, initialize the visited list only once and pass it to the recursive calls:

```
def BackAndForth(AList, end1, end2, visited=None):
    global count
    if visited is None:
        visited = {}
        for i in AList.keys():
            visited[i] = False
    [...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your save, Sir. Now, my program works